# How to implement word to word Co-occurence matrix in python

Tags: python, word2vec

To implement co-occurence matrix in sucha a way that number of times word1 occured in context of word2 in neighbourhood of given value, lets say 5. There are 100 words and a list with 1000 sentences. So how can i calculate co-occurence matrix of size (100* 100) using python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

sentences = ['i go to london', 'you do not go to london','but london goes to you']
vocab = set(word_tokenize(' '.join(sentences)))
print('Vocabulary:\n',vocab,'\n')
token_sent_list = [word_tokenize(sen) for sen in sentences]
print('Each sentence in token form:\n',token_sent_list,'\n')

co_occ = {ii:Counter({jj:0 for jj in vocab if jj!=ii}) for ii in vocab}
k=2

for sen in token_sent_list:
    for ii in range(len(sen)):
        if ii < k:
            c = Counter(sen[0:ii+k+1])
            del c[sen[ii]]
            co_occ[sen[ii]] = co_occ[sen[ii]] + c
        elif ii > len(sen)-(k+1):
            c = Counter(sen[ii-k::])
            del c[sen[ii]]
            co_occ[sen[ii]] = co_occ[sen[ii]] + c
        else:
            c = Counter(sen[ii-k:ii+k+1])
            del c[sen[ii]]
            co_occ[sen[ii]] = co_occ[sen[ii]] + c

# Having final matrix in dict form lets you convert it to different python data structures
co_occ = {ii:dict(co_occ[ii]) for ii in vocab}
display(co_occ)
```

Output:

```
Vocabulary:
 {'london', 'but', 'goes', 'i', 'do', 'you', 'go', 'not', 'to'} 

Each sentence in token form:
 [['i', 'go', 'to', 'london'], ['you', 'do', 'not', 'go', 'to', 'london'], ['but', 'london', 'goes', 'to', 'you']] 

{'london': {'go': 2, 'to': 3, 'but': 1, 'goes': 1},
 'but': {'london': 1, 'goes': 1},
 'goes': {'london': 1, 'but': 1, 'you': 1, 'to': 1},
 'i': {'go': 1, 'to': 1},
 'do': {'you': 1, 'go': 1, 'not': 1},
 'you': {'do': 1, 'not': 1, 'goes': 1, 'to': 1},
 'go': {'london': 2, 'i': 1, 'to': 2, 'do': 1, 'not': 1},
 'not': {'do': 1, 'you': 1, 'go': 1, 'to': 1},
 'to': {'london': 3, 'i': 1, 'go': 2, 'not': 1, 'goes': 1, 'you': 1}}
```

### PS

1. Do text preprocessing yourself (remove punctuations, lemmatization, stemming, blahblah)
2. Continue the code for any conversion you want. You have the dict, you can convert it to sparse matrix or pandas datframe

Comment: @HarikaM Welcome! you may consider accept/upvote if it helped! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ctxs = [
    'krayyem like candy crush more then coffe',
    'krayyem plays candy crush all days',
    'krayyem do not invite his friends to play candy crush',
    'krayyem is smart',
]

l_unique = list(set((' '.join(ctxs)).split(' ')))
mat = np.zeros((len(l_unique), len(l_unique)))

nei = []
nei_size = 3

for ctx in ctxs:
    words = ctx.split(' ')

    for i, _ in enumerate(words):
        nei.append(words[i])

        if len(nei) > (nei_size * 2) + 1:
            nei.pop(0)

        pos = int(len(nei) / 2)
        for j, _ in enumerate(nei):
           if nei[j]  in l_unique and words[i] in l_unique:
              mat[l_unique.index(nei[j]), l_unique.index(words[i])] += 1

mat = pd.DataFrame(mat)
mat.index = l_unique
mat.columns = l_unique
display(mat)
```